# IF ELSE statement to pick choice in model

Tags: python, django-models

I want to find out if possible (maybe I'm just doing it wrong), I have two choices in my model, I want to create a if statement, that when I choose the one option, then it will automatically choose the correct choice on the next model.  I would also just would like to know is this the best practice or is there another way to do it

```
class CalculatorModel(models.Model):
    premium_investment_value_choice = [(10000,'10,000.00'),
                                (15000,'15,000.00'),
                                (18000,'18,000.00'),
                                (20000,'20,000.00'),
                                (30000,'30,000.00')]
    premium_value_choice = [(36,'36.00'),
                            (49,'49.05'),
                            (57,'57.06'),
                            (62.'62.00'),
                            (93.'93.00')]
    premium_payer_name = models.CharField(max_length = 13)
    premium_payer_id = models.CharField(max_length = 13)
    premium_investment_value = models.CharField(max_length = 9, choices = premium_investment_value_choice, default=10000  )
    premium_value = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices = premium_value_choice, default = 36)


    def value(self):
        if self.premium_investment_value == 10000:
            self.premium_value_choice = 36
            return self.premium_value_choice
        elif self.premium_investment_value == 15000:
            self.premium_value_choice = 49
            return self.premium_value_choice
        elif self.premium_investment_value == 15000:
            self.premium_value_choice = 57
            return self.premium_value_choice
        elif self.premium_investment_value == 15000:
            self.premium_value_choice = 62
            return self.premium_value_choice
        elif self.premium_investment_value == 15000:
            self.premium_value_choice = 93
            return self.premium_value_choice
```

Comment: Have you considered using a dictionary? In this case the _keys_ would be `premium_investment_value_choice` and _values_ would be `premium_value_choice`

Answer (score 0):

A very simple approach for your reference using a dictionary:

```
CHOICES = {'10k': 36.00,
           '15k': 49.05,
           '18k': 57.06,
           '20k': 62.00,
           '30k': 93.00}

def value(sel='10k'):  # this is the default
    if sel in CHOICES:
        return CHOICES[sel]
```

Cheers

Comment: thank you this will help me so much, much appreciated